# Browser Default Text Boxes in Materialize css

Tags: html, css, textbox, materialize

I want to apply my own css styles to the text boxes while using materialize css. But I cannot find any option to get the browser default text boxes.

Is there a way by which I can omit the default style provided in the Materialize css framework?

Comment: add the html part you have

Comment: Do you want to use your own styles or the browser default styles?

Comment: I would like to remove the default styles provide by Materialize css. So that I can add my own styles

Comment: Ok, so this has nothing to do with browser default styles then, the title is somewhat misleading. Anyway, you don't need to remove anything, just be at least as specific in your own CSS as the framework is in theirs, and your styles will override those of the framework. Google 'CSS specificity' if you're not familiar with the concept. Also, HTML does not have `textbox` elements, but `input` elements.

Answer (score 13):

Specify input type, then add the browser-default class.

```
<input type="text" class="browser-default">
```

Comment: Works with 1.0.0